# Is intraday trading haraam if you convert losses to investments?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, business, finance

> The name "intra-day trader" refers to a stock trader who opens and closes a position in a security in the same trading day. ... Day traders and intra-day traders are at the top of the risk spectrum. -- [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/university/introduction-stock-trader-types/intraday-traders.asp)

Is intraday trading haraam if you convert it to investment in case of making loss?

Suppose I do intraday trading.

- If the stock I bought goes up, I sell and make profit;
- If its goes down, I convert it to a normal equity order and hold it for the time (days) until it goes up again, and then sell it.

Will that be gambling (haraam) or business?

Comment: following this.

Answer (score -2):

It is Haraam when you invest in a Haraam business like a Casino. If you are invest in an air-line for example you share both profit and loss on your investment so there's no reason for it to be illegal or Haraam.

P.s. I'm neither an expert in investment nor Islam, this is just my opinion.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.